# Hector Cassandra Data Retrieval

Tags: cassandra, key, slice, hector

Is there any way to get all the data from a column family or from a key space?

I can't think of a way of doing this without knowing every single key for every single entry made to the database.

My problem is that I'm trying to create a Twitter clone where each message has its own id, and store those in the same keyspace in the same column family.

But then how do I get them back? I'll have to keep a track of every single id, and that can't possibly work.

Any help/ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer i was looking for is CQL, cassandra's query language. It works similarly to sql which is what i need for the function im after.

this [link](https://github.com/rantav/hector/wiki/Using-CQL) has some excellent tutorials.

Comment: Note that CQL has the same functionality as the Thrift interface - it's just exposed differently.

Comment: The issue was i was new and had little experience, CQL and Astyanax (NetFlix library) are much better ways to go than Hector, mainly because they are so well documented and clear to use, however hector does supply the most powerful interface.

Answer (score 4):

You can retrieve all data from a column family using `get_range_slices`, setting the range start and end to the same value to indicate that you want all data.

- See the [Cassandra FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/FAQ#iter_world)
- See http://aquiles.codeplex.com/discussions/278245 for a Thrift example.

Haven't yet found a handy Hector example but I think it uses RangeSlicesQuery...

However, it's not clear why you want to do this - for this sort of application you would normally look up the messages by ID, and use an index to determine which IDs you need. For example, storing a row for each user that lists all their messages. For example in the messages column family you might have something like:

```
MsgID0001 -> time     text
             1234567  Hello world
MsgID0300 -> time     text
             3456789  LOL ROTFL
```

And then in a "user2msg" column family, store the messages, perhaps using timestamp column names so the messages are stored in sorted in time order:

```
UserID001 -> 1234567   3456789  
             MsgID0001 MsgID0300
```

This can then be used to look up a particular user's messages, possibly filtered by time.

You'd then also need further column families to store user profiles etc.

Perhaps you need to add more detail to your question?

**Update** in response to comment: Yes, if you have one message per row, you have to retrieve each message individually. But what is your alternative? Retrieving *all* messages is only useful for doing batch processing of messages, not for (for example) showing a user their recent messages. Bear in mind that retrieving all messages could take a *very* long time - you have not explained why you want to retrieve all messages and what you are going to do with them all. How many messages are you expecting to have?

One possibility is to denormalise, i.e. in a row for each user, store the entire messages, so you don't have to do a separate lookup step for each message. This doubles the amount of storage required, however.

Comment: You are correct, i read up on it and one way to go is to add an index to messages going into the database and then search for messages that match some criteria like posted by some user.

But if i use a key wont that mean ill only get data for the one message with that key ?